# Нелицеприятный - это какой?

Tags: стилистика

Меня это слово каждый раз вводит в ступор.
Хочется уже понять, в каком значении его можно употребляеть, в каком не должно.
Нелицеприятный разговор - это какой?
Где-то видела объяснения, но очень путанные.

Comment: путаНые...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нелицеприятный - не основанный на лицеприятии, на стремлении угодить кому-либо. Либо еще по другому: с лицом, неприятным Вам, как собеседнику.